# why cant i type in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, types

[here is what is happening, please help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDvJe.png)

I'm unable to type, I don't even have vim emulator plugin. I have  tried doing ctrl
+c then still unable to type, can even view the typing cursor. Even when I create a new file or new folder anything isn't helping

Can someone please please help me i even uninsatlled vs code still i cant happen to type when i create a new file in  a folder. if i create a filw outside a folder then im able to type

Comment: what do you mean "create a file outside a folder"? you mean a "new, unnamed file"?

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.